# How can I get a user's IP from a Blobstore upload handler?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, blobstore

I'm attempting to get the user's IP from inside of my upload handler, but it seems that the only IP supplied is `0.1.0.30`. Is there any way around this or any way to get the user's actual IP from inside of the upload handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking for user IP at the point where you generate upload url via `create_upload_url()`.

The upload handler is actually called by Blobstore upload logic after the upload is done, hence the strange IP.

Comment: How would you recommend doing this? I was thinking of using a regular expression to get the upload key from the `create_upload_url()` call and storing that, along with the user's IP at the time of the URL creation in the datastore. The upload key appears to be passed in the request headers.

Comment: The problem is that you have the users IP before upload happens ( when form is shown), then when upload is finished you get the key (in the upload handler), but you don't get the right IP (sice upload handler is called by GAE internal service.

Comment: Your blobstore upload handler also gets all other form data, so you could create a hidden form field containing IP address.

Comment: This is to be used for verification and banning of users, so simply storing the IP in a hidden field isn't acceptable security-wise. I was considering storing the user's IP in the hidden field encrypted, and then storing a hash of `md5(md5(ip+salt)+md5(uploadkey+salt))`, but that would seem to allow for replay attacks.

Comment: If you store a hash, then you can invalidate (delete) it after upload. This would prevent reply attack.